# mysql selecting data from 2 separate dates chosen dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This is related to Winforms/C#/ MYSQL. 
I have the following table:

Net Amount  /  DATE

50 /2013-3-15

40/ 2013-11-10

30 / 2013-3-25

The program lets the user picks the month he wants to see data from and ideally the output should be a graph ( which i know how to do) to demonstrate the total net amount vs month. The output should be something like the following:

Net Amount / Month

80/March

40/November

Someone suggested I try this :

```
var selectdataforGraph = "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT_NET) AS Amount_Net, MONTH(date_Check) as Month FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE";
                var monthList = string.Join(",", selectedMonth);
                selectdataforGraph += " YEAR(date_check) = " + selected_year;
                selectdataforGraph += " AND MONTH(date_check) in (" + monthList + ")";
```

but when I run the query in the database

```
SELECT SUM(Amount_Net) AS Amount_Net, Month(date_check) AS Selected_Month FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE YEAR(date_check) AND MONTH(date_check) in (1,11);
```

The result is the total Amount_Net Sum for both months something like this:

Amount_Net/Selected_Month

120/11

I did try to make another table with the Net Amount already calculated in per month but since i need to select multiple months in some cases, the column where it has the month is a varchar the month in part of the query above doesn't work.  I could also just redesign the new table with the date column but i feel like I'm so close with the first response. I also know i should use parameters to avoid sql injections but this is more for quick demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` to the SQL Statement after the `where` clause.  Otherwise, MySQL just aggregates everything into a single row, choosing an arbitrary month:

The syntax for that line is:

```
group by MONTH(date_Check), year(date_check)
```

I would also suggest that you include the year in the `select`.

Your statement would be:

```
var selectdataforGraph = "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT_NET) AS Amount_Net, MONTH(date_Check) as Month, year(date_check) as Year FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE";
            var monthList = string.Join(",", selectedMonth);
            selectdataforGraph += " YEAR(date_check) = " + selected_year;
            selectdataforGraph += " AND MONTH(date_check) in (" + monthList + ")";
            selectdataforGraph += " group by MONTH(date_Check), year(date_check)";
```

Comment: Gordon, that was was missing all along, i ran it and also the graph and it  ran  BEAUTIFULLY.  I might make my Monday 8:00 a.m due date yet!!!